# PHP [OOP] : Memory allocation for Inheritance

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, memory-management, extend

**Please see the code bellow:**

```
class A {
    public x = 5;
    public y = 6;
    public z = 7;
}

class B extends A {
    public m = 1;
    public n = 2;
}

$a = new A();
$b = new B()
```

From the above code let **$a** is allocating **x** amount of memory and **$b** is allocating **y** amount of memory;

Now my question is which one is **correct** from bellow?

**x > y**

**x < y**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are my numbers:

```
Starting allocation 62480
Allocated memory for new A() 328
Allocated memory for new B() 496
```

Thus `x < y`

These two class definitions are equivalent

```
class B extends A {
    public $m = 1;
    public $n = 2;
}

class C {
    public $x = 5;
    public $y = 6;
    public $z = 7;
    public $m = 1;
    public $n = 2;
}
```

Meaning that were you to change the definition of B into that of C then the memory usage would be the exact same for using new B() or new C().

To run it yourself use this code (as an example)

```
$start = memory_get_usage();
echo "Starting allocation $start\n";
$a = new A();
$diff = memory_get_usage() - $start;
echo "Allocated memory for new A() $diff\n";
$b = new B();
$diff = memory_get_usage() - $start - $diff;
echo "Allocated memory for new B() $diff\n";
```

Answer (score 3):

You can investigate this by using the [memory_get_usage](http://php.net/memory%5Fget%5Fusage) function.

Answer (score 1):

It should be public $x, $y, $z.

And $b takes up more memory because it has an instance of A inside.

Comment: Nitpicking: It's more like "`$b` *is* an A, but with more stuff" than "has instance of A inside". :)